# Restoring registers in MIPS

Tags: mips, restore, cpu-registers

In the following section of MIPS code, I have to say what registers must be saved during the prologue, and then restored later. I found some including:
$ra, $a0, and $v0

But does anything thats non-obvious also have to be saved/restored, such as $sp or $fp? Thanks.

```
func: #insert function prologue here   
bne $a0, $0, else
addi $v0, $0, 1
j ret
else:
srl $a0, $a0, 1
jal func
addi $v0, $v0, 1
ret: #insert function epilogue here
jr $ra
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $a0 is an input argument to the function and that $v0 is the function's return value.

These registers don't need to be saved and restored, because they will be used/modified.

Your function is recursive so you'll want to save and restore the return address $ra. You don't have to save and restore any registers that you either don't modify or that you leave the function with them in the same state as when the function is entered. In this case, $sp will probably be modified (by you), but you'll restore its previous value before returning.